# How to send the app fcm token to server while uninstalling the app from android device?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

While sending push notifications in a group from app server, Token not registered error is received as response from FCM server. If one token has an error in the group of the tokens, execution gets stopped thereby next set of tokens are not considered to send notifications.

So, when the app is uninstalled I need to detect it and make an api call to the server with the app fcm token to remove the token in the server side. How to detect the app uninstall and make an API call at the time of uninstall?  Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to detect your own app being uninstalled and make an API call from the app, because at that point your app is no longer being allowed to execute code on the device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I wasn't able to detect the uninstall, then how can we avoid the token not registered error in server side. The main problem when a token throws this  not registered error, the next set of tokens in the group will not be executed as the loop exits when this error occur. I have searched a lot about this issue but I did'nt find any solutions so far. Any suggestions from your side?